# Validation without skipping the test cases if one fails

Tags: validation, selenium, testng, assert

I have the following test cases:

1. Login - Logout
2. Login - Search - Logout
3. Login - Search - Click on result - Logout

All these 3 testcases are considered to be independent and are within a single testNg class.

How do I validate the First test case (i.e. how to check if login is successful) ?

I have tried using `assert`, but when `assert` fails the remaining test cases (which are actually independent on the first one) will all be skipped.

How do I make sure that I validate all the test cases and irrespective of whether they pass or fail i should continue to execute all the test cases within that testNG class?

Comment: Please copy your code and the error from the console here. Thank you.

Comment: @Test(priority=0)
  public void Authentication() throws InterruptedException    
 {
  authPage= new AuthPage(driver);
  authPage.login("KYCASH03", "PPCQ@123");
   String actual =driver.getTitle();
  String expected = "General Search";
   Assert.assertTrue(helpdesk.isDisplayed());
   authPage.logout();

Comment: Improvements to formatting, structure and spelling.

Comment: What does you mean that the remaining test cases will all be skipped? You mean the 2. and the 3. test cases or the logout? Because according to your code the logout won't run after the Assert fails, but the logout() action is not a test case.

Comment: by remaining test cases i mean
Login-search_logout and login-search-click on result-logout  scenario for which i have two more methods defined in my Testng class 

since all these three test cases are independent of each other i want all three to run irrespective of the first one failing.

Comment: Every @Test method is independent. They won't get run only if your tests depends on each other (for example if you are using "dependsOnMethods")  or one of your configuration method fails (for example the "afterMethod"). If you copy your full code in your first post wellformatted, maybe we can debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for [ErrorCollector](http://testngdatabind.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/testng/databinding/core/error/ErrorCollector.html). Or you can use custom [SoftAssert](http://beust.com/weblog/2012/07/29/reinventing-assertions/). This is my ErrorCollector realization for **JUnit**:

```
    @Rule //collects errors without aborting test
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

    @Test
    public void SampleTest() throws Exception {

...
        try {

            // Verify label
            Assert.assertEquals("label"
                    ,driver.findElement(By.xpath("some_xpath")).getText());

        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            System.out.println("Report Error: " + e);
            collector.addError(e);
        }

...

}
```